# How to stop the editor-Find Widget box float on top of my file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure how to phrase this well, but an image says more than a thousands words. (version = 1.68.0)

[image: box blocking text in VS Code]

So, there's a hit below the box that I can't see. 
Also, I need to manually close the search box all the time.

Is it possible to have a toolbar-like find/replace input box that pushes down the text so I can actually see the hits at the top of the file?

I'm not able to find useful search results; perhaps I'm not using the right keywords or perhaps I'm missing out on something.

<sup>I like VS Code a lot, but search UI is one of my annoyances.</sup>

Thanks @rioV8, that setting is left at its default (on). Now that I read the description, I understand what is going on. It's a bug; it works when scrolling with the mouse, but not when pressing <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

Also, I need to scroll first, where I would have liked it to push down already when opening the Find Widget.

[image]

Comment: what is your setting: **Editor > Find: Add Space on Top**

Comment: that was the old behavior to always have space on top (smaller text window) they must have changed this to only add space if the first few lines are visible

Answer (score 0):

You can just left few line empty and then text come below, when your search need complete, remove empty line, why wasting more space in extension or something like that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).